# Google's Chrome won't display stylesheet

Tags: php, css, google-chrome

I have this script:

```
<?PHP
$Dokument = $_GET["Ime"];
Switch($Dokument)
{
    Default: Echo "Pogrešno ime dokumenta! Proveri da li postoji."; Exit;
    Case "Style": $Dokument = "Folder/Styles/MainStyle.CSS"; Break;
}
If(File_Exists($Dokument))
{
    Header("Last-Modified: {gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($Dokument))} GMT");
    Header("Content-Type: {MIME_Content_Type($Dokument)}");
    Header("Content-Length: {FileSize($Dokument)}");
    ReadFile($Dokument);
}
Else
{
    Echo "Pogrešno ime dokumenta! Proveri da li postoji.";
}
Exit;
?>
```

It works well with Firefox, but Chrome refuses to display the stylesheet via `<link href="/Izvor?Ime=Style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and it display blank white page instead. It just shows:

```
link
{
    display: none
}
```

Do you need any more details? Can somebody give me an improved version which works within all browsers and php versions? I am an php beginners.

I tried changing the encoding of stylesheet and the web page, but failed as well. Chrome is stubborn. And I expected the stylesheet to be loaded via `/Izvor.php?Ime=main_style`. **This script, actually, is meant to load *all the files* on the page.** Instead of linking them directly like `/Folder/Styles/MainStyle.css`, I want it to be `/Source.php?id=main_style` to load the main style on the page. As I wrote, it works flawlessly on Firefox, but not on Chrome. The same also applies to all other browser ***except*** Firefox. Chrome **CAN** access **ALL** the files *via the php script*, it just **REFUSES** to show/display them on the page.

Any help please?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252467/discussion-on-question-by-wyddoq-googles-chrome-wont-display-stylesheet); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions inside your `header()`s won't get called. Concatenate them like so:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($Dokument)) . " GMT");
header("Content-Type: " . MIME_Content_Type($Dokument));
header("Content-Length: " . FileSize($Dokument));
```

See if that fixes the issues with Chrome

Edit: `mime_content_type` can/will return `text/plain` for a `.css` file. To make sure you use the correct content-type set it manually:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($Dokument)) . " GMT");
header("Content-Type: text/css");
header("Content-Length: " . FileSize($Dokument));
```

Comment: No. It doesn't. Firefox - yes. Chrome - no.

Comment: I keep deleting cache before testing the script in both of the browsers, but the results are the same: Firefox loads well, Chrome doesn't.

Comment: I updated the above script with your code, the way I put it in the script. It doesn't work.

Comment: Will this last edit of yours make the script still load ALL the files, within all the browser and php versions?

Comment: The edit will work for CSS files, which is what we are talking about here

Comment: Yes, but the purpose of the script is to load all the files needed. I don't want to fix one thing, and break another. The script still needs to maintain the functionality of loading all the files, in the all the browsers.

Comment: And you are unable to adapt that change to your code? Use `header("Content-Type: text/css");` for stylesheets, use `header("Content-Type: " . MIME_Content_Type($Dokument));` for any other type.

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable